# How can I assign the due date in Trello via email?

Tags: trello, email

I have been able to create a card in Trello and assign members to the card via email. However, I would also like to be able to set card the due date from the same email. Is it possible to set the due date of a card via email, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, no, at least not directly. You might try contacting Trello to request it as new feature though.

In the meantime, you could try a workaround using another free webapp: Trello [integrates seamlessly](http://help.trello.com/article/763-using-trello-with-sunrise-calendar), including 2-way sync, with Sunrise Calendar which in turn [automatically adds new events from your Gmail](http://support.sunrise.am/article/84-events-added-from-gmail).